# Does Linear Cramer-Shoup have pseudo-random ciphertexts?

Tags: group-theory, chosen-ciphertext-attack, pseudo-random-generator

"Linear Cramer-Shoup" is defined on pages 4 and 5 of $\:$ eprint.iacr.org/2007/074.pdf .

Are the ciphertexts in Linear Cramer-Shoup computationally indistinguishable from uniform 
under a chosen-ciphertext attack? $\:$ (We can assume without loss of generality either that

$M$ is the identity element or that $M$ is a a random element unknown to the adversary.)

This is not homework, and is relevant to a Zero Knowledge

Proof of Knowledge protocol I'm thinking about.

Comment: Note: $\:$ I am asking whether the ciphertexts are indistinguishable from (a) _uniform_ (tuple of group elements), $\:\:$ not whether they are indistinguishable from each other. $\;\;$ (_That_ is proven in the paper.) $\hspace{1 in}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The security claim on page 5 of [the Linear Cramer-Shoup paper](http://eprint.iacr.org/2007/074.pdf) is that their modified scheme is CCA secure, which is weaker than the IND-CCA2 security of the original DDH based Cramer-Shoup scheme. However, from the outline of the security proof, it seems the author actually means the LCS scheme is CCA2 secure.

Also note the first sentence on page 6:

"Clearly, if $A$ has a different advantage in guessing the bit $b$ when $B$ is run with a Linear tuple $(g_1,g_2,g_3,g_1^{r_1},g_2^{r_2},g_3^{r_1+r_2})$ and when $B$ is run with a random tuple $(g_1,g_2,g_3,g_1^{r_1},g_2^{r_2},\eta)$, we obtain a distinguisher for the Linear problem."

The cipher text $(u_1,u_2,u_3,e,v)$ consists of the last three elements of such a linear tuple, plus a blinded message $e$ and a verifier $v$.

Since $u_1 = g_1^{r_1}$ and $u_2 = g_2^{r_2}$ and $r_1, r_2$ are selected at random, these two values are trivially indistinguishable from uniform, because they are uniform. Since $u_3 = g_3^{r_1 + r_2}$, this value is indistinguishable from uniform by the Linear assumption.

The blinded value $e$ is proven to be "independent of the view of the adversary", which I interpret as being indistinguishable from uniform. The proof is interesting. Basically, it is based on the following derived problem:

Given $(g^s,g^t,g^{sa},g^{tb},g^{a+b},g^{ad+be+cf})$ and any number of points on the "plane" $P(x,y) = g^{xd+ye+(x+y)f}$ except $P(a,b)$, output yes if $c = a + b$, no otherwise.

The uniformity of $v$ might be derived using the same technique. Set $g = g_3, g^z = g_1, g^w = g_2$. We then have:

$v^\prime = g^{r_1z(x_1+\alpha{y_1}) + r_2w(x_2+\alpha{y_2}) + r_3(x_3+\alpha{y_3})}$, where $v^\prime = v \iff r_3 = r_1 + r_2$.

Clearly, if $r_3$ is selected uniformly at random, $v^\prime$ is also uniform, so if you are unable to tell if $r_3 = r_1 + r_2$, you are unable to distinguish $v$ from uniform.

Comment: Hi Henrick. Did you read the proof? In page 5, Shacham constructed a DLIN solver B from an IND-CCA2 distinguisher A.

Comment: Yes, but I was stumped by the fact that the author didn't make the corresponding security claim in the above paragraph. If you argue this is a mere terminology issue, I stand corrected.

Comment: The OP is not asking about IND-CCA2 security.  The OP wants to know if the ciphertexts are computationally indistinguishable from uniform random.  That's not implied by IND-CCA2 (you can have IND-CCA2, but not uniform random ciphertexts).

Comment: Is there an implied "One can easily generate a different ciphertext that (with high probability) is valid if and only if the challenge is a valid ciphertext."? $\:$ If no, then I don't see why what I was asking about is obvious.

Comment: @RickyDemer: It is obvious that if the adversary chooses a cipher text completely at random, there is a high probability that the (legitimate) decryptor will fail the verification of $v$. If the adversary is able to detect that, the answer to your question is obviously "no", and I assumed you knew that already. However, if the adversary is unable to detect if a legitimate cipher text is failed or passed, both $e$ and $v$ will, afaict, be indistiguishable from uniform.

Comment: The adversary is able to detect that for any (possible-)ciphertext _other than_ the challenge (possible-)ciphertext. $\:$ With that in mind, the answer does not seem obvious to me. $\hspace{.9 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer: The author of proves that first three elements and then the fourth element of the cipher text 5-tuple are indistinguishable from uniform, as part of the IND-CCA2 proof. The one thing that might not be obvious is what to make of v. However, if you look at how it is calculated, even if you get $H$ and determine $\alpha$, all you get are two known values $c_1d_1^{\alpha}$ and $c_2d_2^{\alpha}$ that are taken to unknown powers $r_1$ and $r_2$, which leads to the Linear assumption: If you are able to construct a $v$ distinguisher, you can use it to create a D-Linear distinguisher.

Comment: If additionally $v$ just the left of those terms, rather than their product, then one would have $g_1,g_1^{r_1},c_1d_1^{\alpha}$, and something that's either $\left(c_2d_2^{\alpha}\right)^{r_1}$ or a random element, which is just an instance of Decisional Diffie-Hellman. $\:$ I don't see how to use the fact that $v$ is the product of those two terms, rather than just one of them. $\;\;$

Comment: LCS is based on the D-Linear assumption http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/wiki/index.php/Discrete_Logarithms#dlinear1. The author doesn't assume the DDH assumption holds in the group, so that ought to be why.

Comment: It's not clear which of those two things you're saying ought to be the reason for the other, but I don't think that matters. $\:$ From my previous comment, it follows that any way of showing (even just for chosen-plaintext) that $v$ is indistinguishable from uniform either also shows that DDH holds or uses the fact that $v$ is the product of its two terms, rather than necessarily equal to one of them. $\:$ If you have method of converting a $v$ distinguisher (given the other 4) to a DLIN solver, can you describe it and be clear where that method uses what I just mentioned about $v$? $\;\;$